# Backing out of a fragment or activity when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-fragments

I have a contact list that takes the user to a contact edit screen. I am trying to handle closing of the edit activity/fragment (contact edit) depending on which one I am currently using. So if I'm using a fragment, I'd like it to close the fragment after saving or deleting from the database, but the same goes for when I'm in portrait/landscape mode on a small device and running an activity. I have the following code that pops up an error (as I expected) when I'm in twopane mode. Basically, I want the user to see a list of contacts, edit the contacts, then see the updated list of contacts plus or minus their edits.

```
// Set the save button to check the required fields, save the contact and finish
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mLastName.getText().toString()) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(mFirstName.getText().toString())) {
      makeToast();
    } else {   
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        getActivity().finish();
   }
  }
});

// Set the delete button to delete the contact and close the fragment
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Delete the contactUri created from an ID passed in from contactActivity
        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(contactUri, null, null);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        getActivity().finish();
    }
  });  
return aView;
```

With the above code I get a NullPointerException at contactEditFragment.onClick

I guess I need a way to differentiate between an activity and a fragment.

```
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at com.somestuff.ContactEditFragment$1.onClick(ContactEditFragment.java:106)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-05 05:40:57.200: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the onContactSelected:

```
public void onContactSelected(String id) {
        if (mTwoPane)
        {
            Log.i("SECOND INSIDE OF ONITEMSELECTED TWO PANE MODE !!! IN CONTACTS ACTIVITY - THE ID IS:", id);
            // In two-pane mode, show the contact edit view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.

                // Create new fragment and transaction
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ContactEditFragment.CONTACT_ID, id);
                ContactEditFragment contactEditFragment = new ContactEditFragment();
                contactEditFragment.setArguments(arguments);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, contactEditFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();

        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected contact ID.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ContactEditActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ContactEditFragment.CONTACT_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
                }
```

Comment: Post your logcat trace

Comment: What is line no 106 in `ContactEditFragment.java` ?

Comment: getActivity().finish();

Comment: Did you used addToBackStack() method during your previous fragment transection? if not, popbackStackImmediate() method should return "NULL".....this might be the reason for your exception.

Comment: I have transaction.addToBackStack in the ContactsActivity. So the contact list should be added to the backstack, thus when I remove the edit page, it should show the contact list again.

Comment: ...But I see what you're saying in the case of an activity (intent) it would look for the backstack that isn't added, as I just use an intent with no mention of backstack... but I'm still not sure how I should handle the differences.

Comment: @k.e.n. `popBackStackImmediate()` will take you to the previous fragment, what is the need of finishing the activity? if you only want to finish() the activity, then remove above two lines

Comment: Give me a few minutes to test this, but what I've found is that in portrait on a cell phone, it doesn't go back to the list right away, I have to re-click on the main menu (contacts item) to get the list to refresh. But in twoPane mode, all is good. So I added the getActivity.finish() to try to accomodate for when I'm just on a small screen.

Comment: Yes, just tried again with the getActivity().finish() commented out, and I can enter new contact information, but when I hit save, the screen just stays the same, where I would like it to go away and re-load the contact list showing the edited information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code, and so far it works as I am expecting:

```
   // Set the save button to check the required fields, save the contact and finish
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mLastName.getText().toString()) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(mFirstName.getText().toString())) {
              makeToast();
            } else {  
                if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }
                else{getActivity().finish();}
           }
          }
        });

        // Set the delete button to delete the contact and close the fragment
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Delete the contactUri created from an ID passed in from contactActivity
            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(contactUri, null, null);

                if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }
                else{getActivity().finish();}
        }
      });  
    return aView;
```